# MariaDB image not executing docker-entrypoint-initdb.d stuff on first run

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am doubting my sanity and I direly need a check if I made a mistake.
To setup a dev system, I need to set user permissions on a mariadb image on the first run.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
#intentionally kept simple, no volume to not populate /var/lib/msqlmariadb:
image: mariadb
build:
context: services/builder-mariadb
ports:
- 3306:3306
```

In my Dockerfile: (among other stuff, using mariadb:latest)

`COPY /static_dev/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

For debugging, my entrypoint does this:

`ls /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -lah`

In the target folder, there will be a "rootFromAll.sql" and a "copyDatabases.sh" which both are NEVER executed. I tested the sql-code after setting up the container and it works, there's also no error-output.

So what I see:

- `docker-compose --force-recreate` works, because mariadb logs that it's setting up the database structure for a first run
- my `ls /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -lah` is being executed, the files are where they need to be, they are with +xr permissions for group and owner, I tried them being owned by root AND by www-data.

What happens? Nothing. Nothing in the given folder is executed, though being stated to be done in the documentation.

The output of the startup is:

```
mariadb-1 | total 24K
mariadb-1 | drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 25 14:45 .
mariadb-1 | drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jan 25 14:45 ..
mariadb-1 | -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 131 Jan 24 09:45 copyDatabases.sh
mariadb-1 | -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 758 Jan 22 15:36 help.txt
mariadb-1 | -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 104 Jan 25 14:10 rootFromEverywhere.sql
mariadb-1 | Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/var/lib/mysql' ...
mariadb-1 | OK
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | To start mariadbd at boot time you have to copy
mariadb-1 | support-files/mariadb.service to the right place for your system
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | Two all-privilege accounts were created.
mariadb-1 | One is root@localhost, it has no password, but you need to
mariadb-1 | be system 'root' user to connect. Use, for example, sudo mysql
mariadb-1 | The second is mysql@localhost, it has no password either, but
mariadb-1 | you need to be the system 'mysql' user to connect.
mariadb-1 | After connecting you can set the password, if you would need to be
mariadb-1 | able to connect as any of these users with a password and without sudo
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | You can start the MariaDB daemon with:
mariadb-1 | cd '/usr' ; /usr/bin/mariadb-safe --datadir='/var/lib/mysql'
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | You can test the MariaDB daemon with mariadb-test-run.pl
mariadb-1 | cd '/usr/share/mariadb/mariadb-test' ; perl mariadb-test-run.pl
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
mariadb-1 | https://mariadb.org/get-involved/
mariadb-1 |
mariadb-1 | STARTING mariadb daemon!
```

Do you guys have any idea?

I was guessing, that maybe the /var/lib/msyql folder is in the base image, therefore always existing (though empty) and therefore preventing the execution of the scripts. Alas, I don't wanna change stuff in the delivered init script - that's not my job...

What do you think?

I tried everything from giving different permissions, forcefully emptying /var/lib/mysql, I checked the SQL statement to be correct (it is, I can access from outside after executing it).

Trouble is, I need to do this after starting the mariadbd, so entryoint is not the right place to do it IMHO.

I also checked past answers on similar questions of stackOverflow, but nothing quite matches this problem.

Comment: Can you add your `ENTRYPOINT` script?

Comment: I'm curious what your `copyDatabases.sh` does. The `mariadb` entrypoint can [restore from backup](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/docker-official-image-frequently-asked-questions/#how-do-i-create-a-mariadb-backup-of-the-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess issue is that you are not calling `docker-entrypoint.sh` from your `ENTRYPOINT` script that is suppose to call function `docker_mariadb_init` that is actually executing all `.sql` and `.sh` files.
Your logs are completely different from default `mariadb` container entry point script

For testing purpose I just executing

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --name mariadb mariadb
```

And I can see in the logs

```
2024-01-25 16:08:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

When I made a typo I got error and container didn't started

Comment: Okay that's interesting. But: you also didn't explicitly run that script, right? You just upped the image. Or do you explicitly mention that init-script in your entrypoint.sh? Or did you specify the docker-entrypoint.sh as ENTRYPOINT= in your dockerfile?

Comment: I didn't, MariaDB team did that, go to https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/mariadb/latest/images/sha256-e4a9a6f3644538084d84aa6ad99a0466d34457b095d06099a99e61f3a73e886c?context=explore and look for `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: Ah I think you gave me the right hint. My entrypoint.sh is executed AFTER the docker-entrypoint.sh, as can be seen in the image data. So obviously I have to copy all that stuff in build time. Which is a bit unpleasant when you want to parametrize at run-time between dev and productive.

You helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: No problem, if you want more accurate help please add your `Dockerfile` and scripts(mainly entry print), would be much easier to know what's going on and less guessing. Also keep in mind you can have only one `ENTRYPOINT` so if you have provided your own it means you overrided what was added by MariaDB team

Comment: Yeah that was the missing information in my head. TY! Willl do better next time :)